# Is there a way to make a homescreen for an app instead of App.js, with React Native Navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am a beginner to React Native and have encountered a problem with navigation. I want my App.js screen to be used for navigation, but I want another file to be the home screen. Is there any way to do this?
This is my App.js code:

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {HomeScreen} from './components/HomeScreen';
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
});

const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
export default App;
```

And this is the code of the page I want to make my home screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
render() {
const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
<Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img1.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img2.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img3.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img4.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img7.jpg')} />
              <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('./components/images/img8.jpg')} />
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
        </>
  );
};
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work for you?

Comment: Normally, with React Native apps, App.js is the home screen. Well, I want to use another file and make that the home screen. That is the second code. By the way, sorry for taking so long to answer.

Comment: In React Native itself there is no definition of a screen. Whatever you pass to `AppRegistry.registerComponent` will be rendered. In your example. App.js is not a screen, e.g. there is no component not render method. It creates app container for navigation, and that container renders other screens, in your case, HomeScreen. So my question was, what doesn't work for you? Is HomeScreen actually not a home screen? I can't seem to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

To make any screen initial you should set it as initialRouteName option like:

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Login: LoginScreen,
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
```

To be able to import HomeScreen (or any other) from another file you need to **export it** from that file first. That part is missing from your example.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is full snack example for your case](https://snack.expo.io/rJKTTYVGU), it is extended from react-navigation basic example, do check their documentation.